# Munkres' Topology theorem 68.7

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, free-product

> **Theorem 68.7** Let $ G = G_1 * G_2 $. Let $ N_i $ be a normal subgroup of $ G_i $, for $ i = 1, 2 $. If $ N $ is the least normal subgroup of $ G $ that contains $ N_1 $ and $ N_2 $, then $$ G/N \simeq \left(G_1/N_1\right) * \left(G_2/N_2\right). $$

**Proof.** The composite of the inclusion and projection homomorphisms
$$ G_1 \longrightarrow G_1 * G_2 \longrightarrow (G_1 * G_2)/N $$

carries $N_1$ to the identity element, so that it induces a homomorphism
$$ i_1 : G_1/N_1 \longrightarrow (G_1 * G_2)/N. $$

Similarly, the composite of the inclusion and projection homomorphisms induces a homomorphism
$$ i_2 : G_2/N_2 \longrightarrow (G_1 * G_2)/N. $$
We show that the extension condition of Lemma 68.5 holds with respect to $i_1$ and $i_2$; it follows that $i_1$ and $i_2$ are monomorphisms and that $(G_1 * G_2)/N$ is the external free product of $G_1/N_1$ and $G_2/N_2$ relative to these monomorphisms.

So let
$ h_1 : G_1/N_1 \to H \ \text{and} \ h_2 : G_2/N_2 \to H $
be arbitrary homomorphisms. The extension condition for $G_1*G_2$ implies that there is a homomorphism of $G_{1}*G_{2}$ into $H$ that equals the composite

$$ G_i \to G_i / N_i  \to H $$

of the projection map and $h_i$ on $G_i$, for $i = 1, 2$. This homomorphism carries the elements of $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ to the identity element, so its kernel contains $N$. Therefore it induces a homomorphism  $ h : (G_{1} * G_{2})/N \to H $ that satisfies the conditions $ h_{1} = h \circ i_{1} \ \text{and} \ h_{2} = h \circ i_{2}. $

the extension condition which it is referring to is :

> **Lemma 68.1.** Let $ G $ be a group; let $\{G_\alpha\}$ be a family of subgroups of $ G $. If $ G $ is the free product of the groups
> $G_\alpha$, then $ G $ satisfies the following condition:
>
> - Given any group $ H $ and any family of homomorphisms $ h_\alpha : G_\alpha \rightarrow H $, there exists a homomorphism $ h : G  \rightarrow H $ whose restriction to $ G_\alpha $ equals $ h_\alpha $,
>   for each $\alpha$.
>
> Furthermore, $ h $ is unique.

**My problem about it is that for the extension condition for $G_1\ast G_2$ we should have $h_i : G_i \to H$ not $h_i : G_i/N_i \to H$**? can someone please help me get it through. am I missing something?

Comment: Define $H_i\colon G_i\to H$ to be the composition of the projection $G_i\to G_i/N_i$ and $h_i$.

Comment: You mean Munkres *Algebraic Topology*.   He has a Topology book too (intro).

Comment: @in some sense no, the second part of Munkres' Topology is also introductory algebraic topology

Comment: Note that the proof explicitly tells you to use the composition I mentioned in my previous comment (I'm assuming everything in then"proof. you wrote you were quoting... though you failed to make this clear). It says the composition property will be applied relative to "the composite $G_i\to G_i/N_i \to H$."